# passwd: Authentication failure on redhat

Tags: authentication, redhat, passwd

I have an application (APP1) which can only be executed by a user with root privileges but not by root.

Hence I have created another user root1 :
adduser -u 0 -o -g 0 -G 0,1,2,3,4,6,10 -M root1

And then when I am trying to assign a password to this user I get an authentication failure.

[root]# passwd root1
Changing password for user root1.
New UNIX password:
BAD PASSWORD: it is based on a dictionary word
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication failure

I looked up a lot on google and tried lot of things suggested but none of them resolved this error.
Could you please help me in resolving the above error, so that I can login to the system using root1 to execute the application(APP1).

Thanks,

Comment: serverfault.com or superuser.com and do `man sudo`

Comment: Anything in your logs? You might want to try http://www.serverfault.com/ too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your password. You cannot change the super user password to something really easy and guessable like "qwerty".

Also, Red Hat has [a nice article about password security.](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/security-guide/s1-wstation-pass.html)

Comment: I tried now with a very secure password (see below we don't see the dictionary warning) but the problem still exists.
By the way my current root password is a word in dictionary. 

Example:
[root@smh pam.d]# passwd root1
Changing password for user root1.
New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication failure

Comment: Okay, so it's something else then. Have you checked `/var/log/secure` for any errors?